# File path to change the product url

Tags: product-urls

Currently url is forming by product name and i want to change it by using the sku_id.for this change where i change the code. To change the product url which file has to be modified. please help me i am new to magento.

Comment: Why are you asking same question multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can update **URL Key** field value of product to update product URL. You can write there SKU of the product.